# Max size problem when trying to upload a file in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, upload, max, size

I am out of explanation for the apparently very basic problem of "The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2097152 bytes." on Symfony.

In my php.ini, I have set the 'upload_max_filesize' to '512M' and the 'post_max_size' to '1024M'.

In my entity for which i am trying to upload this file, i have set the 'maxSize' assert attribute like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     maxSize = "1024M",
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/xml"}
 * )
 */
private $fileName;
```

When i remove the 'maxSize' attribute in my entity, the message only changes to "The file is too large. Allowed maximum size is 2 MiB."

The file i am trying to upload is 7,203Ko
It works nicely when i upload a file inferior to 2Mo.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please check `phpinfo();` that your php.ini working and your changes initialized on there?

Comment: There you go! It is set at 2Mo on my phpinfo. But...why the hell?!

Comment: So, i am using WAMP.
When i try to edit the php.ini file via the WAMP menu (icon => PHP => php.ini OR icon => PHP => PHP configuration => upload_max_filesize / post_max_size), it actually edits the file located in C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\php.ini

BUT my phpinfo() uses the one located in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini

Weird. But anyway, whether i change one or the other, it doesn't work! I didn't forget to restart WAMP everytime i made some changes.

Answer (score 2):

I ve been through the same problem, this is how i fixed it:

Run `phpinfo()` to find where the **php.ini** file is.
(There was no **Loaded configuration File**  used in my case)

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc   
Loaded Configuration File:        (none)
```

Go to the **/etc** folder where you should found a **php.ini.default** file.
Copy the **php.ini.default** and rename it to **php.ini** using the following command:(sudo is for mac users)

```
sudo cp php.ini.default  php.ini
```

Open the newly created file with vim (or any editor) to edit it.

```
vim php.ini
```

Change this line to the size you need:

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

save and exit.
relaunch you server, it must be working

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

Actually 2 php.ini are "used".
When using the WAMP process to edit the php.ini file (click on icon + php + php.ini OR click on icon + PHP + PHP configuration + whateveryouwannachange), it is using the one located at "C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\bin\php.ini"

When i use phpinfo() to locate the php.ini file used, it shows me the one with the path "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\php.ini"

Why is it different? No idea.

I could do whatever changes i wanted, it was never taken into account, because... i am using the "symfony/web-server-bundle" library as a web-server and i have to close the server every time i update the php.ini file so that it works.